# When does the constructor of a Scala user-defined annotation class gets executed?

Tags: scala, constructor, annotations

I defined a Scala class *MyAnnotation*, used to annotate certain classes within my program:

```
case class MyAnnotation() extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
println("MyAnnotation initialized") // doesn't get printed
}
```

Which is used in the following way:

```
@MyAnnotation()
class MyClass() {
...
}
```

However, when I instantiate the *MyClass* class, the constructor of *MyAnnotation* doesn't get executed. I.e., the println does not happen.

```
val x = new MyClass()
// nothing gets printed
```

Sumarized: is there any way to provide a constructor to a user-defined annotation class that gets executed when another class annotated with that annotation is instantiated?

Comment: Answer is **NO**.

Comment: Technically, the answer is yes: make it a macro annotation (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) and transform the constructor(s) of the annotated class in the macro. Whether this is code you want to write and maintain, is your decision. I certainly don't, which is why this isn't an answer :)